# Batch file with FTP runs from command line, but not as scheduled task

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, cmd

I have a batch file which at some point starts a ftp session. This ftp should create a log file. 
When I run the batch file the command line, it works fine, but when it is started by the Windows task scheduler it does not. It does not create the ftp log file and even the ftp does not work.

This is a part of the batch file:

```
unzip -o %sourcedir%%FileName% -d %sourcedir%
rename "%sourcedir%OriginalFileName" newfilename.txt
move %sourcedir%%FileName% "%sourcedir%Archive\%FileName%"
ftp -s:ftpscript.scr >D:\TEMP\log\FTPgetLOG.txt
FC /a /w %sourcedir%t2dircompare.txt %sourcedir%target2dir.txt | FIND "FC: no dif" > nul
```

I start the batch file from the task scheduler with the argument: > D:\TEMP\log\DistributeFile.txt
When I look at the log file of the batch file, the ftp part looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ftp -s:PutT2DirToATBAS01.SCR  1>D:\TEMP\log\FTPgetLOG.txt
```

For some reason, it adds a space and a 1

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the write / execute permission. Have you tried to make the scaduler run the task as the same user with which your command line is working?

Comment: Try `ftp -s:ftpscript.scr >D:\TEMP\log\FTPgetLOG.txt 2>&1` to see errors in your log file. However, that `1>` redirector is the same as the `>` one. FYI `command >file 2>&1` is a way how to redirect errors and output to one file.

Comment: You need to put in the FULL path to where the script is `ftp -s:"D:\Some\Place\ftpscript.scr" ...`

Answer (score 0):

`1>` means the same as `>`. It is always corrected in batch files as `1>` is the correct format and `>` is compatability. 0 = stdinput, 1 = stdoutput, 2 = stderror. 3+ = a random file if one is open.

You need to check your environment and your TS account as a few don't have network access.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. It helped me a bit further, but the solution was to change the action in task scheduler like this:

Program/script: **CMD**

Add arguments: **/c start "" "D:\temp\RunBatchFile.bat"**

Start in: **D:\temp****

So, DO NOT put the name of the batch file in the "Program/script" field.